# How to setCanceledOnTouchOutside option set in angular 2 AlertController

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am Use ionic 2 and angular 2.I have Some Exist Alert my Project.Like this

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({    
  title: '<b>Message</b>',      
  subTitle: 'you have already In time!  Please be first update Outtime',    
  buttons: [{     
    text: 'OK',          
    handler: () => {    
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage);  
        }

      },]}); alert.present();
```

I need Not close my alert On Touch Outside.Like android Dialog Option `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` .Please Any One Help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the option `enableBackdropDismiss`. Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/#advanced).

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({    
  title: '<b>Message</b>',      
  subTitle: 'you have already In time!  Please be first update Outtime',
  enableBackdropDismiss:false,//here
  buttons: [{     
    text: 'OK',          
    handler: () => {    
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage);  
        }

      },]}); alert.present();
```

Comment: it's Working.. Thank @suraj